# Importar várias libs em um único include em c

Tags: c, include, lib

Existe alguma forma de importa todas as libs do meu programa em apenas um `include` como em outras linguagens : `import re, datetime, math` ( Python ) ?

Depois de ler sobre diretivas de pré processamento [aqui](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C/Pr%C3%A9-processador) ( Pouco se fala do `include` nessa página do Wiki ) eu pensei em algo do tipo importar as libs padrões do sistema ( `stdio, stdlib, stdbool, string, locale` ... ) como libs externas `" stdio.h, stdlib.h "`, porém acho que não exista ( Ou desconheço ) um delimitador para colocar entre as mesmas para que funcione corretamente ... só por curiosidade mesmo se alguém souber ficaria grato.

Além do artigo da Wikipédia : [Cpp Reference Preprocessor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include) ( Falam do C ++ )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe; o preprocessador C é uma linguagem de macro bastante primitiva, e pouco integrada com o resto da linguagem (como o próprio Dennis Ritchie [afirma](https://heim.ifi.uio.no/inf2270/programmer/historien-om-C.pdf#page=8)).

O que você pode fazer é criar um arquivo de cabeçalho separado que inclua ele próprio todos os cabeçalhos padrão que você quer incluir, geralmente chamado `common.h` ou `config.h`:

```
#ifndef DEFINICOES_DE_CABECALHO
#define DEFINICOES_DE_CABECALHO

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

#endif
```

E depois, nos seus arquivos fonte, basta dizer

```
#include "common.h" // ou "config.h", ou qualquer nome que você tenha escolhido
```

Comment: Só complementando porque a resposta responde o perguntado, o mecanismo do Python é absurdamente diferente do C, nem conceitualmente são a mesma coisa, apesar de parecer para um leigo. inclusive a terminologia usada na pergunta não é adequada, apesar ser compreensível.

Comment: Qual seria a terminologia correta ? - A primitividade desejada do ' c ' as vezes incomoda de fato, mas é assim que ela é e é poderosa né ha ha

Comment: O @bigown deve estar se referindo ao fato de que bibliotecas não são _importadas_ em C, mas arquivos cabeçalho são _incluídos_ (isto é, são incluídos textualmente no corpo do arquivo fonte); esses cabeçalhos _devem_ declarar a interface de uma biblioteca, mas não necessariamente (podem ser usados para implementar uma técnica de metaprogramação chamada [X Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro), em vez disso, por exemplo).

Comment: @LuisSouza exato, esse é o poder do C. e o Wrtmute entendeu corretamente o que eu disse. Pode parecer bobagem, mas isto tem fortes implicações.

Comment: Muito legal, a sim eu estou abstraindo a minha pergunta mas tenho o entendimento do que é importado pois estudei recentemente Tad em ' c ', já a parte do X Macros não sabia vlw por informar ( Vou procurar sobre )